Puzzlement on memory statistics in Linux
I am working on an embedded Linux system (Kernel-5.10.186) on a SOC platform.
Now I am doing long-time testing to collect memory statistics in the system.
And I had a shell script to collect memory usage every 5 seconds, and I got following 2 outputs which made me puzzled.
================ No. 37 =================
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          55096       15864       28336         100       10896       36220
Swap:             0           0           0
Active(anon):        148 kB
Inactive(anon):     3736 kB
AnonPages:          3848 kB
  108 dummyx.sh     3292 1056
  112 test_proc        178m 5528
  136 dbus-daemon      4144 1856
  171 adbd              35m 1620
  173 udc_daemon       3292 1288
  174 sh               3292 1392
  175 watchdog         3160 1080
test_proc's RSS: === 5660672
......
================ No. 2584 =================
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          55096       15808       27612         100       11676       36272
Swap:             0           0           0
Active(anon):        132 kB
Inactive(anon):     3256 kB
AnonPages:          3332 kB
  108 dummyx.sh     3292 1056
  112 test_proc        178m 6220
  136 dbus-daemon      4144 1856
  171 adbd              43m 1860
  173 udc_daemon       3292 1288
  174 sh               3292 1392
  175 watchdog         3160 1080
test_proc's RSS: === 6369280

I am watching the memory usage of the system and test_proc, the test_proc RSS is increased from 5660672 to 6369280 by about 700KB, but the used and available memory are almost the same!! Why?

Just a guess:  test_proc had already requested and received 1,555 (or more) memory pages before Sample 37.  By Sample 37, the process was using 88% of the pages, and by Sample 2584 usage had grown to 1,555 pages.  The "Mem" stats didn't change because the count of pages allocated to test_proc hadn't changed, only how much of them it was using.

I just omit the test logs between sample 37 and sample 2584. And the RSS is increasing slowly until some sample point, where it is constant.  So as your comment, it is possible for the test_proc's RSS to be constant at some time, but the statistics confused me as I asked in the question. My understanding is RSS is the real memory used by process, and available is the memory available for the system, they should have relationship, but my test did NOT show this relationship.
